# Working while TFS Migration

Tags: tfs, migration

Is it possible for developers to work offline while TFS is migrated? Can they checkout the code before migration and check it in after migration is done?

Source is TFS Express and Target is TFS 2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the migration will carry over the workspaces as well as all files that are checked out prior to migration. Once the migration is done, when the users point to the new server TFS and VS will do some automatic rewiring because the databases have the same GUIDs. Also note that you will want to make sure that they don't want to interact with the old server while the migration is underway.