# Keep working during TFS Side-by-side upgrade

Tags: tfs, migration, upgrade, commit

I know someone answered this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15618933/working-while-tfs-migration)
but there is only one answer and no feedback from the author. I'd like to have more sources before starting my upgrade.

So, we're planning on upgrading TFS 2010 to TFS 2018 but we need to keep working while doing so.
Is it possible to have on going modifications while upgrading to TFS 2018 and commit them when the upgrade is done ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by "working". If you're talking about source control, then yes, the answer to the other question is accurate. If you're talking about work item changes, builds, etc, then the answer is "no".

When doing upgrades on TFS instances considered critical for business, the best process to use is this:

1. Do a test upgrade first, leaving the existing instance online.
2. Fix any problems that you discover that occur post-migration and, if necessary, write scripts to quickly apply the fixes
3. Re-test the upgrade process, including applying your fixes
4. Do the final upgrade over a weekend or overnight, outside of normal business hours